# GRASS GIS and Liss4MX

Tags: grass-gis, terrain

i am working on grass gis. how to use grass gis for liss4 of IRS-P6.I have to do atmospheric correction for hilly terrain data.i would like to use grass's i.atcorr. may i know the dependencies and how to customize it for my problem.will liss4 data directly used in that module?or only it is limited to specific sensors. i would also like to inform that i have compiled OTB4.0 but the code assumes that surface as Lambert which not suitable to my study. hence i want to use grass gis for it. will grass also has same assumption of lambertian surface? please suggest me.

Comment: The i.atcorr in GRASS GIS support LISS/IRS 1C. If the specifications for LISS 4MX are different, we may add them to i.atcorr...

Comment: can we able change the grass source code for LISS4MX sensor for atmospheric correction module? or it will work for  sensors mentioned only?

Comment: We can add new sensors. Please check http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Atmospheric_correction#How_to_add_new_sensors_to_i.atcorr (page bottom) - essentially we need the sensor functions as a table, the rest is done with a script.